# Scheme Language Constructs for Calculating Nth Roots

Tags: math, functional-programming, scheme

Scheme has a native function (sqrt x) which, obviously, finds the square root of the variable, x.  Are there any native functions or constructs useful in determining whether a parameter meets the predicate of a fraction?

I need to determine, for x, whether it is any fraction, say 3/2, so that in my recursive exponent function, I can process it accordingly.  I simply need to determine whether I have an integer or fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [`exact-integer?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._exact-integer~3f%29%29) predicate:

```
(exact-integer? 3/2)
=> #f
(exact-integer? 3)
=> #t
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  I think I was almost there in MITs text.  I just need to read that closer in the future.